# Bulk update in SQLAlchemy from text query result/ResultProxy or dict

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I would like to bulk update an ORM table in SQLAlchemy from a query for which I only have the text and a database connection. I cannot easily (I believe) reflect the source query in the ORM because it could come from an unlimited set of tables. The extra wrinkle is that I would like to update a key-value HSTORE column (postgres). I think I can figure out how to do this row-by-row, but would prefer a bulk UPDATE FROM-style operation.

To keep it simple:

```
class Table(Base):
    __tablename__= 'table'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    hstore = Column(MutableDict.as_mutable(HSTORE))

query_to_update_from = 'select id, attr1, attr2 from source_table where id between 1 and 100'
```

I would like to update Table.hstore with {'attr1':attr1, 'attr2':attr2} where ids match. I want any columns not named `id` to update the hstore.

I know I can do `session.execute('select id, attr1, attr2 from source_table where id between 1 and 100')` and get a list of column names and row data easily. I can make a list of dictionaries from that, but can't figure out how to use that in a bulk update.

I have also tried making a query().subquery out of the raw text query to no avail, understandably since there isn't the required structure.

I am stumped at this point!